# nginx 404 for assets

Tags: php, nginx

I have next conf file. `/` points to SPA and `/api` to my backend server. now i need to set static files. so i do.

```
location / {
    root /var/www/prod2020/dist;
}

location /js {
    root /var/www/new-rte2020/public/js;
}
location /images {
    root /var/www/new-rte2020/public/images ;
}
location /css {
    root /var/www/new-rte2020/public/css ;
}
```

But this doesnt seems to work, im getting 404 from nginx. How can i make it work. in a next way:

`https://mysite/` - `/var/www/prod2020/dist` - works

`https://mysite/js` - `/var/www/new-rte2020/public/js` - **doen't work**

`https://mysite/js/app.js` - `/var/www/new-rte2020/public/js/app.js` - **doen't work**

`https://mysite/js/widget/w.js` - `/var/www/new-rte2020/public/js/widget/w.js` - **doen't work**

Here is almost full conf file

```
#server {
#       if ($host = a.rte.im) {
#           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#       } 
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#   server_name a.rte.im;
#       return 404; # managed by Certbot
#}

server {

#   listen 443;
#        ssl on;
#       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s.rte.im/fullchain.pem;
#       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s.rte.im/privkey.pem;


#   root /var/www/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name a.rte.im;
    location ~ /js {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public/js;
    }
    location ~ /images {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public/images ;
    }
    location ~ /css {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public/css ;
        try_files $uri /var/www/new-rte2020/public/css$uri;
    }
    location /api {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location /chatify {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    

    location /storage  {
                alias /var/www/new-rte2020/storage/app/public;

    }      
    location /payment-form {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /upgrades/payment-form {
        root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

        location /test {
                root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    location / {
        root /var/www/prod2020/dist;
    }

    
    location ^~ /assets/  {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            root /var/www/prod2020/dist;
        }

    
    location ~ \.php$ {
         root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;
         try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
    }
    error_page  405     =200 $uri;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.rte.im/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.rte.im/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = a.rte.im) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name a.rte.im;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: You should use `root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;` - the `js`/`css`/`images` is already part of the URI and the path to the filename is simple concatenation of the `root` value with the URI value.

Comment: @RichardSmith declaring a root doen't work and i need to keep `location /` where it is

Comment: Your `root` statements in `location ~ /js`, `location ~ /css` and `location ~ /images`, are wrong - they all need to be `root /var/www/new-rte2020/public;`. This has nothing to do with the contents of the `location /` block.